# How to read data from a string

Tags: matlab

I have a string in the following format :

`fileName.jpg,10,20,10,10,...,12,14,True`

Basically, I have a string with comma separated values. The first value is a string, then it follows an array of 100 values and lastly another string being true or false.

Is there a way or directly reading these values into 3 variable? Two strings and an array?
The array of values might contain `n\a` values which I want to treat as `-1` or something similar or by using a cell array and having an empty cell for those? Can you recommend me something for this type of problem?

Comment: Did you try `regexp(s,',','split')` ? or simply `strsplit()` for your 100 numeric values

Comment: But how should I consider the string values at the beginning at the end?

Comment: Textscan should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
n = 100; % number of integers between filename and logical values

M = textscan(str, ['%s' repmat('%d',1, n) '%s'], 'delimiter', ',',...
    'TreatAsEmpty', 'n\a', 'EmptyValue', -1, 'CollectOutput', true);
```

The result `M` is a cell array with the file name in the first cell, the 100 integer values in the second, and a string containing the logical value in the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit` and extract the values from your String and store them in separate variables

Code Sample:

```
a = strsplit("fileName.jpg,10,20,10,10,...,12,14,True",",")
fileName = a(1)
flag = a(end)
data = a(2:end-1)
```